# Aurelia: Stylesheets not being requested

Tags: aurelia

I'm re-building my website using Aurelia as a learning exercise having previously followed the tutorial on the official website without issue. However, I want to load an existing local (to the project) stylesheet but for some reason they aren't being requested/loaded by the framework.

I have a standard CSS link in my index.html file:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="styles/base.css" />`

and when I load my site in a browser I can see from the dev tools that the declaration is there. if I right click the resource and say 'open in new tab' then it loads the stylesheet fine, so the path is OK. Looking at the network tab though, its not being requested at all.
I've tried moving the line from index.html to app.html but it makes no difference.

Looking at the docs (http://aurelia.io/docs.html#templating) it says you can import a stylesheet outside of a template tag, but again I've tried this and it isn't making the request for the CSS file.

Is there some bespoke means of loading a stylesheet in Aurelia that I'm missing?

Comment: There way you are loding stylesheet is not something aurelia/framework specific, so it should work just fine. It has nothing to do with aurelia in this case. Putting `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="styles/base.css" />` in head should load it as soon as path is correct.

Comment: That was my understanding, but even if I put a completely dummy URL in (e.g.
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="http://some.other.com/styles/fake.css" />) there's no 404, no error in the console, nothing. Its as if Aurelia is hijacking (and cancelling) these requests?

Comment: If you remove Aurelia from index.html altogether (config.js, system.import, etc), do still have this issue? Can you see styles downloaded or 404?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`link` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) doesn't have a `src` attribute. I think you just need to switch to the `href` attribute instead.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/base.css" />`